# Retrieve operational LDAP attributes with Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-ldap

I am using `spring-security-ldap` to add LDAP authentication to my application. It is configured like so:

```java
auth.ldapAuthentication()
          .userSearchBase(ldapConfigProperties.getUserSearchBase())
          .userSearchFilter(ldapConfigProperties.getUserSearchFilter())
          .contextSource()
          .managerDn(ldapConfigProperties.getManagerDn())
          .managerPassword(ldapConfigProperties.getManagerPassword())
          .url(ldapConfigProperties.getUrl())
          .and()
          .userDetailsContextMapper(ldapContextMapper);
```

The `ldapContextMapper` is an instance of a custom class called `LdapUserContextMapper` that implements `UserDetailsContextMapper`.

Inside `mapUserFromContext()` I use the `DirContextOperations` to retrieve several attributes from the LDAP user to construct a concrete `User` POJO. However, I just can't get access to operational attributes like `memberOf`. I tried every solution I could possible find on the web, but nothing seems to have worked.

For instance, `ctx.getObjectAttributes("memberOf")` returns null. Attempting to call `ctx.search("", "", searchControls)` with custom `SearchControls` with `SUBTREE_SCOPE` yields a `not implemented` exception from `DirContextAdapter`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I eventually ended up instantiating my own `ContextSource` and then using a custom `ObjectPostProcessor`, just as described in [this issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/4309).